# Bower installs wrong version of foundation-sites

Tags: json, zurb-foundation, bower

I'm trying to install foundation-sites version 6.2.0.
Here is my bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "4.6.1",
    "foundation-sites": "6.2.0"
  }
}
```

However, when I look at the installed foundation-sites library I see that it is version 6.4.3 (bower.json in the foundation-sites directory):

```
{
  "name": "foundation-sites",
  "version": "6.4.3",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": [
    "scss/foundation.scss",
    "dist/js/foundation.js"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "config",
    "docs",
    "gulp",
    "lib",
    "test",
    "composer.json",
    "CONTRIBUTING.md",
    "gulpfile.js",
    "meteor-README.md",
    "package.js",
    "package.json",
    "sache.json",
    ".editorconfig",
    ".npm",
    ".gitignore",
    ".npmignore",
    ".versions",
    ".babelrc",
    "yarn.lock"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">= 3.0.0",
    "what-input": "~4.1.3"
  }
}
```

Even the UI in Visual Studio gives the impression that 6.2.0 was installed:

[image]

EDIT:
On further inspection, I noticed that .bower.json contains the right version (6.2.0).
The wrong version (6.4.3) is in bower.json which seems to be the version that is installed.

What could be the issue here; why is 6.4.3 being installed?

Comment: Can nobody help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

In general bower is dead and is not recommended anymore. You can switch to npm or yarn.

Regarding your issue.
I can not reproduce this and you did not provide more information.

```
bower install
bower not-cached    https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites.git#6.2.0
bower resolve       https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites.git#6.2.0
bower not-cached    https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.6.1
bower resolve       https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.6.1
bower download      https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/archive/v4.6.1.tar.gz
bower download      https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/archive/v6.2.0.tar.gz
bower progress      font-awesome#4.6.1 received 1.0MB
bower progress      foundation-sites#6.2.0 received 1.0MB
bower progress      font-awesome#4.6.1 received 1.2MB
bower progress      foundation-sites#6.2.0 received 1.3MB
bower progress      font-awesome#4.6.1 received 1.5MB
bower progress      foundation-sites#6.2.0 received 1.5MB
bower progress      font-awesome#4.6.1 received 1.8MB
bower progress      foundation-sites#6.2.0 received 1.8MB
bower progress      font-awesome#4.6.1 received 2.1MB
bower progress      foundation-sites#6.2.0 received 2.1MB
bower extract       font-awesome#4.6.1 archive.tar.gz
bower progress      foundation-sites#6.2.0 received 2.3MB
bower progress      foundation-sites#6.2.0 received 2.6MB
bower extract       foundation-sites#6.2.0 archive.tar.gz
bower resolved      https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites.git#6.2.0
bower resolved      https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.6.1
bower not-cached    https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input.git#~1.1.2
bower resolve       https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input.git#~1.1.2
bower cached        https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.4
bower validate      2.2.4 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#~2.2.0
bower download      https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input/archive/v1.1.4.tar.gz
bower extract       what-input#~1.1.2 archive.tar.gz
bower resolved      https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input.git#1.1.4
bower install       foundation-sites#6.2.0
bower install       font-awesome#4.6.1
bower install       jquery#2.2.4
bower install       what-input#1.1.4

foundation-sites#6.2.0 bower_components\foundation-sites
├── jquery#2.2.4
└── what-input#1.1.4

font-awesome#4.6.1 bower_components\font-awesome

jquery#2.2.4 bower_components\jquery

what-input#1.1.4 bower_components\what-input
```

And the bower.json file content:

```
cat bower_components/foundation-sites/bower.json
{
  "name": "foundation-sites",
  "version": "6.2.0",
  "main": [
    "scss/foundation.scss",
    "dist/foundation.js"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "config",
    "docs",
    "gulp",
    "lib",
    "test",
    "composer.json",
    "CONTRIBUTING.md",
    "gulpfile.js",
    "meteor-README.md",
    "package.js",
    "package.json",
    "sache.json",
    ".editorconfig",
    ".npm",
    ".gitignore",
    ".npmignore",
    ".versions"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.2.0",
    "what-input": "~1.1.2"
  }
}
```

Which bower version do you use? Mine is 1.8.0.